# refrence sent id through a sql statment

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

i want to reference sent Id that is coming from the frontend

```
def list(self, request):
        queryset = Course.objects.raw('select * from course inner join course_categories on (course.id = course_categories.course_id) where category_id = {}').format(???????)

        serializer = CourseSerial(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

I want to handle a sent id and put it in my sql statement

Comment: how the id is coming from the front-end?

Comment: sent by a get request

Comment: on the link? on the request body? The code above isn't not enough to help you. Please, include your route definition

Comment: "select * from course inner join coursecategory on (course.id = coursecategory.course_id) where category_id = $sent_id "

Comment: this is the sql statement .. I want to change $sent_id  by the id that is coming from the fornt end( angular)

Comment: I know what you want to do. I need to see your `Router.get()` for this `GET`

Comment: You access the parameter the same way here that you would do it in any other part of the application.

Comment: Just put the variable that contains the id into the parentheses. But for better safety you should use a prepared statement with `cursor.execute()`.

Comment: Why do you want to use raw SQL at all? There is nothing complicated about this query, you should use normal orm methods.

Answer (score 0):

if you are sending the id you can access it by **request.GET['sent_id']** since its a get query.